# updating multiple times a large matrix in RcppArmadillo

Tags: c++, r, memory-management, rcpp, armadillo

I have a main function calling multiple times a helper function that creates a rather large matrix (10^8 complex numbers). Until now I've had the helper function allocate the memory every time and build the matrix from scratch. Would it be preferable to allocate the memory once in the main function, and pass its pointer to the helper function to update it?

My naive test below suggests that this is indeed more efficient.

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <iostream>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// this version returns a new G0 everytime
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::cx_mat helper1(int N, int ii) {

  arma::cx_mat G0 = arma::eye<arma::cx_mat>( N, N );
  // dummy calculation
  G0 = 0 * G0 + ii;    
  return(G0);
}

// this version updates G0 defined elsewhere
// [[Rcpp::export]]
void helper2(int N, int ii, arma::cx_mat& G0) {
  // dummy calculation
  G0 = 0 * G0 + ii;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::cx_double  main1(int N, int Nl) {

  arma::cx_mat G0 ;
  int ii;
  for (ii=1; ii<Nl; ii++){
    G0 = helper1(N, ii);
  }
  return(G0(1,1));
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::cx_double main2(int N, int Nl) {

  arma::cx_mat G0 = arma::eye<arma::cx_mat>( N, N );
  int ii;
  for (ii=1; ii<Nl; ii++){
    helper2(N, ii, G0);
  }
  return(G0(1,1));
}

/*** R
main1(100, 10)
main2(100, 10)
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(main1(3000, 50), main2(3000, 50), times = 5)
# Unit: seconds
# expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max
#   main1(3000, 50) 7.160945 7.180199 7.218132 7.203668 7.237876 7.307974
# main2(3000, 50) 2.432682 2.432864 2.446226 2.436771 2.439675 2.489136
*/
```

Of course, in practice the program performs all sorts of calculations, so I'm not sure I should rely on the results from this dummy example. Before I bite the bullet and convert all my code to follow this 'update' strategy, I'd like to be more confident that it's a good approach...

Comment: Do you now about i) bigmemory (though I do not know if it does complex matrices) and/or ii) Rcpp::XPtr to just wrap you own pointer to an external object?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Short answer: no, I don't. I've heard of them, but so far happily avoided dealing with objects that are too big to fit in the RAM. Do you think there would be a performance gain for the situation I'm describing? (I was under the impression that I'm not making unnecessary copies here, by passing only references).

Comment: See the [Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org) for examples of either.

Comment: OK thanks, I'll take a look. I thought those strategies only proved useful for datasets that didn't fit comfortably in the RAM but I guess I was wrong.

Comment: bigmemory was explicitly designed for 'fits in RAM but should be outside the R memory pool' and added disk backing later.  We used it at work for exactly this purpose: hold a big dataset, and shared (read-only by our choice) access pointers even across several threads.  I can  promote these comments to an answer if they suit...

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I'll experiment a bit later to see how much gain I should expect (and if it's not too difficult to interface). I'll report back.

Comment: Please feel free to post an answer with your comments, but I'd like to understand better why bigmemory can be helpful when everything still fits in the RAM. I can't find a clear explanation. I've just run an example from the Rcpp gallery and it does seem to provide a speed up, but I don't get why. Unfortunately, it's not an option anyway, because it doesn't handle complex matrices.

Comment: With regards the narrower question I initially posted, is it a reasonable approach to have my helper functions update big objects allocated only once? (I prefer the explicit assignment, visually, but it does appear to slow things down...)